# AJAX console result NaN 404 Not found

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to make search engine with AJAX. When i type on search box, it does nothing. When i inspect elemen and open the console, it says `script.js:19 GET http://localhost/var/www/html/pendaftaran-siswa/NaN 404 (Not Found)`

When i click Sources, it's says failed to load sources on line 19. Here's my script:

```
var keyword =  document.getElementById('keyword');
var searchButton = document.getElementById('search-button');
var container = document.getElementById('container');

keyword.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
const src = e.target.value


    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if( xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            container.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;


        }
    }

    xhr.open('GET', 'ajax/mahasiswa.php?keyword=' + keyword.value, true);
    xhr.send();
});
```

Is there a solution to this problem? Sorry for my bad english

UPDATE, now it turns like this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function query() in S:\xampp\htdocs\var\www\html\pendaftaran-siswa\ajax\mahasiswa.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in S:\xampp\htdocs\var\www\html\pendaftaran-siswa\ajax\mahasiswa.php on line 11
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition_()

Comment: fix to this: ``xhr.open('GET', `ajax/mahasiswa.php?keyword=${keyword.value}`, true);``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe

```
xhr.open('GET', 'ajax/mahasiswa.php?keyword=' * keyword.value, true);
```

should be

```
xhr.open('GET', 'ajax/mahasiswa.php?keyword=' + keyword.value, true);
```

to further debug:

```
console.log('ajax/mahasiswa.php?keyword=', keyword.value);
```

Comment: I'd throw in `+ encodeURIComponent(keyword.value)` just be safe

Comment: still getting the error, script.js:19 GET http://localhost/var/www/html/pendaftaran-siswa/NaN 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @Vich that's highly unlikely. Are you sure you changed `*` to `+`?

Comment: @Vich if your code has changed, please update your question. Also, clear your browser cache

Comment: question updated, browser cache cleared, debug shows ajax/mahasiswa.php?keyword=

Comment: Update, now it turns like this: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function query() in S:\xampp\htdocs\var\www\html\pendaftaran-siswa\ajax\mahasiswa.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in S:\xampp\htdocs\var\www\html\pendaftaran-siswa\ajax\mahasiswa.php on line 11

Comment: but - looking at the original question - 'ajax/mahasiswa.php?keyword=' * keyword.value is still wrong, and 'ajax/mahasiswa.php?keyword=' + keyword.value is correct